# String triangle pattern does not print the correct output (when the string contains more than one word)

Tags: python, string, design-patterns, while-loop, string-length

Trying to create a triangular print pattern for an input string caused the following problem.
Here is the code:

```
string=input("Please enter your word: ")
printable=""

l=0
while l<len(string):
    for i in string:
        printable+=i
        print(printable)
        l+=1

q=0
while q!=len(string):
    for z in string:
        string=string.replace(string[-1],"")
        if string=="":
            break
        print(string)
```

For an input containing only one word ("Python") it works fine and it prints out:

```
P
Py
Pyt
Pyth
Pytho
Python
Pytho
Pyth
Pyt
Py
P
```

The problem starts when a string with a space between the words is entered ("Elvis Presley"):

```
E
El
Elv
Elvi
Elvis
Elvis 
Elvis P
Elvis Pr
Elvis Pre
Elvis Pres
Elvis Presl
Elvis Presle
Elvis Presley
Elvis Presle
Elvis Prsl
Evis Prs
Evi Pr
Evi P
Evi 
Evi
Ev
E
```

Most probably it is because when it reaches back Pres"l" it also removes the "l" in Elvis. How can I fix that? Would be glad if you assist me.
Thank you!

Comment: No, the " " is not a problem. The problem appears when the program reaches back a character that is to be found multiple times in the string. Please check the banana example below.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with multiple words, the problem is when there are duplicate characters in the string. `string.replace(string[-1],"")` will remove *all* the occurrences of the last character. So when the last character is `l`, it removes the `l` in `Elvis` as well.

Use a slice to remove the last character, not `replace()`.

```
string = string[:-1]
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that when I entered "Banana" (a very good example, see below).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't work with a single word string, too.
if I enter "Banana" the output is:

```
B
Ba
Ban
Bana
Banan
Banana
Bnn
B
```

When the program reaches a repeating character it is being removed from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second loop `string=string.replace(string[-1],"")`. If you replace the last character of string you replace all instances. So that `'Elvis Presle'.replace('e', '')` results in `"Elvis Prsl"`.

Instead of `replace` use indexing - `string = string[:-1]`.

P.S. You can simplify looping through string like this:

```
while string:
    string = string[:-1]
    print(string)
```

Comment: I can just add one if statement to avoid printing one blank line:
`
while string:
    string = string[:-1]
         if string==""
               break
    print(string)
`

Comment: Yes or simplify it further: `if string: print(string)` no need for break. If you like my answer then feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on

```
string=string.replace(string[-1],"")
```

It replace letters with nothing so when letter 'e' was found all of them are erased same as letter 'l'. You can use indexing instead of letters.

```
l=0
while l<len(string)+1:

    print(string[:l])
    l+=1
```

It means that take letter by letter starting from the left to the right. Then you can use reverse of the slicing method. string[:-1] means that take until to the last letter.

```
l=1
while l<len(string)+1:

    print(string[:l*-1])
    l+=1
```

Thus the entire code will be:

```
string=input("Please enter your word: ")

l=0
while l<len(string)+1:

    print(string[:l])
    l+=1

l=1
while l<len(string)+1:

    print(string[:l*-1])
    l+=1
```